# Toggle (ToolTip) Hover Text for disabled Silverlight button

Tags: silverlight, button

My grid displays a button in a column.  By default, Silverlight disables Tooltip display for disabled button.  I've tried to work around this by placing button and tooltip object inside of border control.  I want to show tooltip when button disabled and not show when enabled.  I tried to bind tooltip to button IsEnabled property but doesn't work.  Here is code:

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent"  >
<ToolTipService.ToolTip  >
  <ToolTip Content="Ticket Required"   Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled,     ElementName=btnEdit, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToInvisibilityConverter}}"   />
</ToolTipService.ToolTip>
<Button x:Name="btnEdit" Content="Add"   Margin="0, 0, 7, 0" Width="35" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Command="{Binding EditCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"  Style="{StaticResource SquareButtonStyle}" Click="EditButtonClick" IsTabStop="True"/>
</Border>
```

The tooltip displays regardless whether the button is enabled/disabled. What am I doing wrong.  I sense something wrong with my binding or is this not the way to do it.  Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that element binding does not work here for some reason. The binding mechanism cannot find the button you are trying to bind to. It works if you bind to a property on, say, a viewmodel instead. Here is a working example:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication14.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication14"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="White">

        <Grid.Resources>

            <local:ReverseBoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="ReverseBoolToVisibilityConverter"></local:ReverseBoolToVisibilityConverter>

        </Grid.Resources>

        <Border HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Background="Transparent">

            <Button x:Name="btnEdit"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonEnabled}"
                    Content="Add"
                    Margin="0, 0, 7, 0"
                    Width="35"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    Command="{Binding EditCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                    IsTabStop="True" />

            <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Content="Ticket Required"
                         Visibility="{Binding IsButtonEnabled, Converter={StaticResource ReverseBoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        </Border>

        <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Margin="0 -50 0 0"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsButtonEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Is Enabled"></CheckBox>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the code-behind including the converter class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SilverlightApplication14
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _IsButtonEnabled;

        public bool IsButtonEnabled
        {
            get { return _IsButtonEnabled; }
            set
            {
                _IsButtonEnabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsButtonEnabled");
            }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            IsButtonEnabled = true;

            LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public class ReverseBoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && (bool)value)
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not working is Whenever you use command with button its enalble disable properties are drive by Command's CanExecute method.

Also because its method you can't straight away bind Command's CanExecute method. So you need some workaround to get value of CanExecute method into property and bind that property to Visibility of ToolTip.